# PHP SOAP how to modify response

Tags: php, soap

Okay, first let me show you my script.

```
<?php  
$soap_exception_occured = false;

$wsdl_path = 'http://vrapi.xyz.com/?wsdl';

$response = '';

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); // disabling WSDL cache

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path);
    }

catch(SoapFault $exception) {
    $soap_exception_occured = true;
    $response .= '\nError occoured when connecting to the SMS SOAP Server!';
    $response .= '\nSoap Exception: '.$exception;
    } 

/* Create a Recharge at VR */
$client_id = 'appl45fgysssl';

$balance_info = new stdClass(); 
try {  
$balance_info = $client->GetBalanceInfo($client_id); 
} 

catch(SoapFault $exception) { 
 $soap_exception_occured = true;  
 $response .= "\nError occoured at method GetBalanceInfo($client_id)";  
 $response .= "\nSoap Exception: ".$exception; 
 } 

 /* Do something or print results */
 if($soap_exception_occured || $balance_info==null) echo $response; 
 else print_r($balance_info); 

 ?>
```

And Output in browser

```
stdClass Object ( [client_user_id] => appl45fgysssl [available_credit] => 9755 [last_updated_time] => 2012-07-29 14:30:15 )
```

I want to display the data into a well arranged format. Ex.

Client: appl45fgysssl

Balance: 9755

Time: 2012-07-29 14:30:15

Please help me to do that. Any reference should be fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output the results in a human readable form, as opposed to print_r, you could simply cycle through the results in a foreach loop;

```
foreach($balance_info as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key: $value<br />";
}
```

Or for more specific naming, if you know what the columns are, using a `->` to access the objects properties and echo them out;

```
Client: <?php echo $balance_info->client_user_id; ?><br />
Balance: <?php echo $balance_info->available_credit; ?></br />
Time: <?php echo $balance_info->last_updated_time; ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Answer (score 1):

As @Stu said, that would be the perfect answer for you. Check this part.

```
/* Do something or print results */
if($soap_exception_occured || $balance_info==null) echo $response; 
else { ?>

        Client: <?php echo $balance_info->client_user_id; ?><br />
        Balance: <?php echo $balance_info->available_credit; ?></br />
        Time: <?php echo $balance_info->last_updated_time; ?>
<?php } ?>
```